# Как обрабатывать события подключенные в библиотеке WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, behaviors

Не могу обработать событие, которое содержится библиотеке, искал на форумах, информация расплывчива,новичок MVVM еще полностью разобрался.
Пробовал так
Подключил библиотеку
`xmlns:tobii="clr-namespace:Tobii.Interaction.Wpf;assembly=Tobii.Interaction.Net"`  `

```
Button x:Name="btn1"  Width="400" Height="400"
      tobii:Behaviors.IsGazeAware="True"
      Content="Кнопка"          
             >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName=" tobii:Behaviors.HasGazeChanged" >
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethink}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Но ничего не происходит. Само событие работает, если обработчик в MainWindow.xaml.cs но это вроде не правильно с точки зрения архитектуры. Как быть?

Comment: В написании  `Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethink}` нет ошибки? Это `DoSomethink` реализует `ICommand`?

Comment: Да, реализует, это работает если прописать например
`<Button Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethink}"`

Comment: А кнопка тут при чем? Как это должно работать? Вы же не событие кнопки обрабатываете?

Comment: Библиотека для трекера фокуса взгляда человека, если человек посмотрел на кнопку должно срабатывать событие
Если написать так
`<Button tobii:Behaviors.HasGazeChanged="btnHadGaze"`
то все работает, но это создает код в MainWindow.xaml.cs
А то как это не по MVVM-ному
Поэтому я хочу чтоб было через триггер как ввопросе, но не работает

Comment: Меня лично тут смущает слово `Behaviors`, а они немного по-другому используются (`<i:Interaction.Behaviors><нужное поведение></i:Interaction.Behaviors>`). Может вам надо в эту сторону копать? А событие и прочее не трогать, пусть кнопка реализует простой `Command="..."`.

Comment: ```<Button x:Name="btn1"  Width="400" Height="400"
                     tobii:Behaviors.IsGazeAware="True"
                     Content="Кнопка" 
                Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethink}"
                 >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <tobii:Behaviors.HasGazeChanged></tobii:Behaviors.HasGazeChanged>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>``` так студия ругается Элемент свойства не должен содержаться напрямую в другом элементе свойства

Comment: Обращайтесь к собеседникам вот так: @EvgeniyZ. Это позволяет увидеть ведомление о том, что вы написали.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо

Comment: Ну в коде выше вы не поведение (Behavior) пытаетесь подключить, а само событие. Вы ищите именно `Behavior`, если нету, то не пойму тогда к чему там слово `Behaviors`... Ну а так, я увы, помочь тут вряд ли чем смогу, ибо для тестов надо брать эту библиотеку и пробовать, а чтоб проверить, что это работает, надо это устройство иметь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , может я не совсем корректно описал вопрос,
вот ссылка как раз на то что меня интересует https://qna.habr.com/q/623844, но ответа на том ресурсе я не понял